# Why doesn't addTextObject() with a jQuery variable work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-desktop-gadgets

When developing a Windows Vista/7 Gadget, and putting out text using [addTextObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa359355(VS.85).aspx)(), this works:

```
var mytext = "Hello";
document.getElementById("background").addTextObject(mytext , "Verdana", 11, "white", 10, 10);
```

But I cant get this jQuery selector into a variable to work:

```
var mytext = $("#myid").text();
document.getElementById("background").addTextObject(mytext , "Verdana", 11, "white", 10, 10);
```

It doesn't work, it only writes an empty string.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why.
The content in my div was added dynamically using jQuery.

```
<div id="myid"></div>

$("#myid").append("somedata"); 
var mytext = $("#myid").text();
System.Debug.outputString(mytext); // Empty
```

For some reason, this doesn't work in the Gadget.
It does work in a plain HTML file though...

Static content do work in the Gadget:

```
<div id="myid">somedata</div>

var mytext = $("#myid").text();
System.Debug.outputString(mytext); // Ok
```

Can anyone explain how I can query dynamically added content in a Sidebar?
UPDATE:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923489/is-there-a-way-to-query-html-xml-content-from-a-variable-using-jquery) solved my problem.

Comment: I've had cases where I had to relinquish control in order to allow the browser to do its work. To do this, I put the code into a function called by setTimeout().

Comment: I found a workaround, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923489/is-there-a-way-to-query-html-xml-content-from-a-variable-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try [$(document).ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myid").append("somedata"); 
    var mytext = $("#myid").text();
    System.Debug.outputString(mytext);
});
```

Maybe your code is running before the DOM completes.