# Is there a way to query HTML/XML content from a variable using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, variables, css-selectors

If I have HTML content in a variable like so:

```
var data = "<div id='myid'><div id='subid'>Text</div></div>";
```

Is there a way to query this using jQuery and selectors?
As this, if it were HTML DOM:

```
var data = $("#myid > #subid").text();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's [context](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext):

```
$doc = $("<div id='myid'><div id='subid'>Text</div></div>");
var data = $("#subid", $doc).text();
```

Your example is wrong in that it is trying to access the elements by class (".subid") instead of by id ("#subid") - also, if you have an element's ID, it is not necessary to do something like "#myid > #subid" as since there is only one ID per document (if you're doing things properly, at least) then jQuery can just do the native document.getElementById() to find the element. I tested the above and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks Paolo, that worked like a charm. (Of course, it should be the # prefix, I was a little bit sloppy when typing an example)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this selector.

```
var data = "<div id='myid'><div id='subid'>Text</div></div>";
var subIdText = $(data).find('#subid').text();
```